# will be exempt or will be exempted?

Tags: grammar, tense, grammaticality-in-context, past-participles

> People performing "critical" tasks including air traffic controllers will be exempt under new rules.

I saw this sentence from a news article. I was taught that *will be* is followed by *past participle*. Past participle of *exempt* is *exempted*.

Is "*will be exempt*" correct or is it a typo here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct, but convey slightly different emphasis, this is because of a slightly unusual situation that adjective and past participle are not derived the same way, as such exempted (p.p.) and exempt (adj) are distinct words.

Exempt - adjective and verb

Exempted - p.p. of exempt

Other examples:

- Open/Opened
- Legal/Legalized

Examples taken from: https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/140293-Exempt-vs-exempted